# fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: openssl, centos7, tls1.3

Operating system: Centos7

I am trying to build stackless python which has dependency on openssl.
I need to use openssl 1.1.1d to support tls1.3
I have added tarball openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz in my makefile.

When I do make it is showing me below error,

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DSTACKLESS_FRHACK=0 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I./Stackless  -DPYMALLOC_DEBUG -DPYMALLOC_LIMIT_OBJECT_SIZE=268435456 -DSTACKLESS_LIMIT_STACK_SIZE=1310720  -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/itertoolsmodule.c -o Modules/itertoolsmodule.o
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DSTACKLESS_FRHACK=0 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I./Stackless  -DPYMALLOC_DEBUG -DPYMALLOC_LIMIT_OBJECT_SIZE=268435456 -DSTACKLESS_LIMIT_STACK_SIZE=1310720  -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/_hashopenssl.c -o Modules/_hashopenssl.o
**./Modules/_hashopenssl.c:39:25: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/evp.h>**
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Modules/_hashopenssl.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/builddir/project/build/tarball/stackless-2716-export'
make: *** [build/dp-stackless-python-2.7.16.tw1.bfeature-centos7_support_OpenSSL_1.1.1d_for_profiler_scanning_LOCAL.r20200407145948_UNCOMMITTED-6cc0cf0.bLOCAL.tar.bz2] Error 2
ERROR: Command failed. See logs for output.
```

From some other sources on stackoverflow I found that it needs openssl-devel packag.
However openssl-devel with version 1.1.1d which supports tls1.3 is not available for Centos7.

Can anyone please guide me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use the available `openssl11-libs` and `openssl11-devel` RPM packages from EPEL 7 rather building OpenSSL by yourself (to also cover future security updates)? It's providing the same OpenSSL version like RHEL/CentOS 8 does.

Before building a software relying on the newer OpenSSL, you need to extend 
`$CFLAGS` and `$LDFLAGS` slightly, e.g. like this:

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $(pkg-config --cflags openssl11)"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $(pkg-config --libs openssl11)"
```

Or, if `./configure` supports passing a pkg-config `*.pc` file directly, use `openssl11` there.